# FeathersJS API + Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, feathersjs

I would like to if there is way to use a Firebase Realtime Database with Sequelize on a FeathersJS API.

My API is setup with a local mariadb this way, in the sequelize.js:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    'dbName',
    'username',
    'password',
     {
       host: 'mariadb',
       dialect: 'mysql'
     }
   );
  const oldSetup = app.setup;

  app.set('sequelizeClient', sequelize);

  app.setup = function (...args) {
    const result = oldSetup.apply(this, args);

    // Set up data relationships
    const models = sequelize.models;
    Object.keys(models).forEach(name => {
      if ('associate' in models[name]) {
        models[name].associate(models);
      }
    });

    // Sync to the database
    app.set('sequelizeSync', sequelize.sync());

    return result;
  };
};
```

I need everything here especially relationships.

So I am able to use realtime db/firestore db with feathersJS sequelize?

- I tried to use the [firstore-sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-sequelize) package, but the API doesn't start and got this:

```
/node_modules/feathers-sequelize/lib/index.js:31
2022-12-08 12:15:50       Sequelize = options.Model.sequelize.Sequelize;
2022-12-08 12:15:50                                           ^
2022-12-08 12:15:50 
2022-12-08 12:15:50 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Sequelize')
```

The only thing I have from realtime database is databaseURL, or maybe should I use the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try edit your code to this:

```
// const Sequelize = require('sequelize');  //remove this
const sequelize = require("firestore-sequelize"); //replace with this
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

module.exports = function (app) {
  //   const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  //     'dbName',
  //     'username',
  //     'password',
  //      {
  //        host: 'mariadb',
  //        dialect: 'mysql'
  //      }
  //    );

  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
  
  sequelize.initializeApp(admin)
  
  const oldSetup = app.setup;

  app.set("sequelizeClient", sequelize);

  app.setup = function (...args) {
    const result = oldSetup.apply(this, args);

    // Set up data relationships
    const models = sequelize.models;
    Object.keys(models).forEach((name) => {
      if ("associate" in models[name]) {
        models[name].associate(models);
      }
    });

    // Sync to the database
    app.set("sequelizeSync", sequelize.sync());

    return result;
  };
};
```

As for the authentication/credentials [read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/) this first since google has to recognize you and permitted access.